# C# Regular Expression Match Failing

Tags: c#, regex

Here's the regular expression pattern:

```
string testerpattern = @"\s+\d+:\s+\w\w\w\w\w\w\s+..:..:..:..:..:..:..:..\s+\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+\s+\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+\s+""\w +""";
```

Here's some lines of text I want to match. there will be 1 or more spaces at the beginning of the line.  When I get it working I will modify it to do named matches.  Basically I want most of the line without doing multiple matches on a line for each pattern.

```
 2: fffc02 10:00:00:05:1e:36:5f:82 172.31.3.93     0.0.0.0         "SAN002A"
 3: fffc03 10:00:00:05:1e:e2:a7:00 172.31.3.168    0.0.0.0         "SAN003A"
 4: fffc04 50:00:51:e8:cc:2f:ae:01 0.0.0.0         0.0.0.0         "fcr_fd_4"
```

here's the static class I wrote to do the matches.  It works elsewhere in my program so I'm assuming that it's the pattern that's a problem.  the pattern matches successfully on  Regexr.com

```
public static class RegexExtensions
{
    public static bool TryMatch(out Match match, string input, string pattern)
    {
        match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
        return (match.Success);
    }

    public static bool TryMatch(out MatchCollection match, string input, string pattern)
    {
        match = Regex.Matches(input, pattern);
        return (match.Count > 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would removing a space between `\w` and `+` inside double-quotes at the end fix the problem?

Comment: yeah that was it.  I've been staring at this for 15 minutes trying to figure it out.  new question... one of the lines of input may or may not have a '>' preceding the left hand double quote at the end of the line.  I know the regular expression match would be \? for 0 or 1 but how do I escape that so that C# doesn't think it is part of naming the match? or would it be easier to just replace it with whitespace if it exists prior to the match? I tried '\>\?' as an escape, that fails the match.

Comment: Another way to escape a single character is with square brackets, i.e. `[>]?`

Comment: ok.  trying this [>]*    breaks the match.  I may just check and if it contains that, do a replace with a space then run the match. I don't really need that character anyway.

Comment: For the "\d+.\d+." bit, do you want to escape the .?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, surely remove the space between `\w` and `+` if you intend to match one or more word characters.

Next, if you need to match a literal dot, you must either escape it - `\.`, or put into a character class - `[.]`.

Also, you can make use of *limiting quantifiers* to shorten the pattern *if you do not need captures*. See how your pattern can be written:

```
string pat = @"\s+\d+:\s+\w{6}\s+(?:..:){7}..(?:\s+\d+(?:\.\d+){3}){2}\s+""\w+""";
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cs%2B%5Cd%2B%3A%5Cs%2B%5Cw%7B6%7D%5Cs%2B(%3F%3A..%3A)%7B7%7D..(%3F%3A%5Cs%2B%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%2B)%7B3%7D)%7B2%7D%5Cs%2B%22%5Cw%2B%22&i=%202%3A%20fffc02%2010%3A00%3A00%3A05%3A1e%3A36%3A5f%3A82%20172.31.3.93%20%20%20%20%200.0.0.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22SAN002A%22%0D%0A%203%3A%20fffc03%2010%3A00%3A00%3A05%3A1e%3Ae2%3Aa7%3A00%20172.31.3.168%20%20%20%200.0.0.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22SAN003A%22%0D%0A%204%3A%20fffc04%2050%3A00%3A51%3Ae8%3Acc%3A2f%3Aae%3A01%200.0.0.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%200.0.0.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22fcr_fd_4%22&o=m) (where `\w{6}` matches 6 "word" chars, `(?:..:){7}` matches 7 sequences of 2 any chars other than a newline followed with `:`, etc.)

If you need to *capture*, still, you can use the ideas I outlined above:

```
\s+(\d+):\s+(\w{6})\s+(..(?::..){3}):((?:..:){3}..)\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+){3})\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+){3})\s+"(\w+)"
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cs%2B(%5Cd%2B)%3A%5Cs%2B(%5Cw%7B6%7D)%5Cs%2B(..(%3F%3A%3A..)%7B3%7D)%3A((%3F%3A..%3A)%7B3%7D..)%5Cs%2B(%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%2B)%7B3%7D)%5Cs%2B(%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A%5C.%5Cd%2B)%7B3%7D)%5Cs%2B%22(%5Cw%2B)%22&i=%202%3A%20fffc02%2010%3A00%3A00%3A05%3A1e%3A36%3A5f%3A82%20172.31.3.93%20%20%20%20%200.0.0.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22SAN002A%22%0D%0A%203%3A%20fffc03%2010%3A00%3A00%3A05%3A1e%3Ae2%3Aa7%3A00%20172.31.3.168%20%20%20%200.0.0.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22SAN003A%22%0D%0A%204%3A%20fffc04%2050%3A00%3A51%3Ae8%3Acc%3A2f%3Aae%3A01%200.0.0.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%200.0.0.0%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22fcr_fd_4%22&o=m)

[image]

Comment: I need the captures.  I got it working by surrounding the '>' with [].  I also figured out that while C# allows you to continue the value of a string on the next line at assignment, this breaks a regular expression match.  In the code I had the pattern on 2 lines for readability so  I didn't have to scroll right to see the entire pattern,   The dots seem to match fine using the C# @"" syntax for string literals

Comment: An unesacaped `.` matches any symbol but a newline, it would match `§` if it were there. See my updated suggestion *with capturing groups* around your values.